# Transcribing / translating snippet of Burmese (to English)

Tags: transliteration, translation

So I have this picture of Burmese text which I think might be interesting to know the meaning of. I know translation is off-topic here, but I gather that asking which tools are recommended is allowed here.

I have extracted the relevant part of the picture, in which the characters are easily recognisable. I have tried [newocr](https://www.newocr.com/), which according to my Google search should support Burmese, but it returns gibberish in Latin letters and Arabic numbers. I have also tried tried the CamScanner app based on [this page I found](https://phandeeyar.gitbook.io/pandatoolbox/using-google-ocr-for-myanmar-lang), but it doesn't support Burmese in the settings.

Short of hiring a professional translation service, what are my best options of getting it translated or transcribed (so I can try Google Translate)? It's only one A4 paper with a single word at the top and three lines below it (in a really large font).

I have no Burmese language experience, so even trying to match a few lines' worth of characters with an alphabet online seems like a tedious task.

Comment: Welcome to LL.SE. Good first question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest option is to use some language exchange (which are many, google is your friend). You promise to do some work for a Burmese speaker, and get something in return.

I would assume there are many Burmese speakers who are interested in improving their speaking proficiency (they already can read and write some English, which you have sufficient skills, even if not your L1). So for you, it might be exchanging an hour of talking with some Burmese who is learning English, for transcribing that pic, and even translating it. You even have something to talk about :-)

Next questions would be, which language exchange has decent number of Burmese speakers? :-)

I have no profitable interest (my only interest is to get more members to it, because I am a member - network effect increases the value of my connections), but I use mylanguageexchange.com, which has cheap "golden" membership (you need to be "gold member" to be able to contact other people who are not). Standard "freemium" price model.

From the (rather aged) design, mylanguageexchange.com looks like a labor of love of small group, not very profitable, which is OK with me.

Comment: Interesting idea (I didn't know about those exchanges, but I found a tag on this SE). Not sure what work I'd be qualified to do for a Burmese speaker, but it's something I'll look into. If you have a more specific suggestion (e.g. a specific site) then please ket me know. :)

Comment: Interesting, that's actually the one I found too by googling ;p.

Comment: That's how I found it too :-)